# Pipe does not give the same result every time in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, named-pipes

I am trying to read a file by the parent process, send the content to two child processes and child processes write content to a shared memory segment. However, at each run, I get different outputs and I cannot figure out why.

I use two named pipes and after writing to shared memory, the parent process opens the shared memory and reads the content of each memory.

The first child writes to memory as it gets but the second child converts to hexadecimal.

Here is my main function; assume that `stringtohex()` works correctly.

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid_1, pid_2;

    int fd, sd;     // pipes
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    const char infile[] = "in.txt";

    FILE *tp; // file pointers

    pid_1 = fork();

    if (pid_1 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork 1 failed");
        return(1);
    }

    if (pid_1 > 0)
    {
        pid_2 = fork();

        if (pid_2 < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork 2 failed");
            return(1);
        }

        if (pid_2 > 0) // parent
        {
            tp = fopen(infile, "r");

            if (tp == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading", infile);
                return(1);
            }

            mknod(PIPE_NAME_1, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
            mknod(PIPE_NAME_2, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

            fd = open(PIPE_NAME_1, O_WRONLY);
            sd = open(PIPE_NAME_2, O_WRONLY);

            if (fd > 0 && sd > 0)
            {
                char line[300];

                while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), tp))
                {
                    int len = strlen(line);
                    int num_1 = write(fd, line, len);
                    int num_2 = write(sd, line, len);
                    if (num_1 != len || num_2 != len)
                        perror("write");
                    else
                        printf("Ch 1: wrote %d bytes\n", num_1);
                    printf("Ch 2: wrote %d bytes\n", num_2);
                }
                close(fd);
                close(sd);
            }

            fclose(tp);

            wait(NULL);

            int shm_fd = shm_open("Ch_1", O_RDONLY, 0666);

            if (shm_fd == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed: Shared Memory 1");
                exit(-1);
            }

            int shm_sd = shm_open("Ch_2", O_RDONLY, 0666);

            if (shm_sd == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed: Shared Memory 2");
                exit(-1);
            }

            void *ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

            if (ptr == MAP_FAILED)
            {
                printf("Map failed 1\n");
                return -1;
            }

            void *ptr2 = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_sd, 0);

            if (ptr2 == MAP_FAILED)
            {
                printf("Map failed 2\n");
                return -1;
            }

            fprintf(stdout, "Normal input: \n%s\n", ptr);
            fprintf(stderr, "Hexadecimal: \n%s\n", ptr2);
        }
        else // second child
        {
            // open shared memory segment
            int shm_child_2 = shm_open("Ch_2", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

            // configure the size of the shared memory segment
            ftruncate(shm_child_2, SIZE);
            // map the pointer to the segment
            void *ptr_child_2 = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_child_2, 0);

            if (ptr_child_2 == MAP_FAILED)
            {
                printf("Map failed 3\n");
                return -1;
            }

            // configure named pipe
            mknod(PIPE_NAME_2, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
            sd = open(PIPE_NAME_2, O_RDONLY);

            if (sd > 0) // reading from pipe
            {
                int num;
                char s[300];

                while ((num = read(sd, s, sizeof(s))) > 0)
                {
                    // convert to hexadecimal
                    char hex[strlen(s) * 2 + 1];
                    stringtohex(s, hex);
                    // write into segment
                    sprintf(ptr_child_2, "%s", hex);
                    ptr_child_2 += strlen(s) * 2;
                }
                close(sd);
            }
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else // first child
    {
        // create shared memory segment
        int shm_child_1 = shm_open("Ch_1", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

        // configure the size of the shared memory segment
        ftruncate(shm_child_1, SIZE);
        // map the pointer to the segment
        void *ptr_child_1 = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_child_1, 0);

        if (ptr_child_1 == MAP_FAILED)
        {
            printf("Map failed 4\n");
            return -1;
        }
        // configure named pipe
        mknod(PIPE_NAME_1, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
        fd = open(PIPE_NAME_1, O_RDONLY);

        if (fd > 0) // reading from pipe
        {
            int num;
            char s[300];
            while ((num = read(fd, s, strlen(s))) > 0)
            {
                // write into segment
                sprintf(ptr_child_1, "%s", s);
                ptr_child_1 += strlen(s);
            }
            close(fd);
        }
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example input file has:

```
Harun
sasmaz
59900
1234
Aaaa
```

Results are:

Normal input: 
HARUN
sasmaz
59900
1234
Aaaa4

Hexadecimal: 
484152554E0A7361736D617A0A35393930300A313233340A41616161

or

Normal input: 
HARUN
sasmaz
asmaz59900
1234

Aaaa

Hexadecimal: 
484152554E0A7361736D617A0A35393930300A0A313233340A41616161FF03

Comment: I find your code really unreadable. I would advise not to create such long functions - split functionality between small readable parts. `read` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`. `strlen` returns `size_t`, not `int`. Please use consistent indentation. `strlen(s)` - is `s` really zero terminated? For example in `read(fd, s, strlen(s)))` - `s` is unintialized. You can't assume what you read from `read(fd, s, sizeof(s))` that it will be zero terminated. You should use `read` return value to determine length of data.

Comment: I am getting used to C programming and I am aware of the confusing structure of code but I am trying to focus on the task. Thank you for advice. I don't think that I got your question

Comment: In `while ((num = read(sd, s, sizeof(s))) > 0)
            {
                // convert to hexadecimal
                char hex[strlen(s)*2 + 1];` - why would `strlen(s)` work? You do not write zero byte in the pipe.

Comment: How can I fix them? I am confused about char * and strings in C

Comment: If you learn and practice good coding hygiene, you'll be less confused in the future.  You'll also find it easier to get good online assistance.  The first thing you should do, is break your program down into smaller, more understandable parts.  Start small and build on success.

Comment: On a multi-core machine (are there any single-core machines left that aren't more or less embedded?), the scheduling of the three processes is not deterministic.  That means operations can occur in different orders.  Reading that you're using two named pipes and shared memory immediately suggests "run away" to me.  Especially the shared memory bit.  How are you coordinating and controlling access to the shared memory?  Can't you at least create functions `child_1()`, `child_2()` and `parent()` to separate the three sets of operations?

Comment: Your code: `while ((num = read(sd, s, sizeof(s))) > 0)
                {
                    char hex[strlen(s) * 2 + 1];` should use `num * 2 + 1` in the array definition.  Your `stringtohex()` should be told how many bytes to convert.  It is probable that there are bugs because `stringtohex()` is not given a string but a byte array without a null byte marking the end.  You know what happens when you "assume" something works?  It makes an ASS of U and ME.  You've not shown code to dump what's read, or what's produced by `stringtohex()`, for example, so you don't know what's going on.

Comment: Why use `mknod()` to create FIFOs instead of `mkfifo()`?

Comment: Note that the parent only waits for one, not both, of the children to die.

Comment: I changed to mkfifo and all strlen calls were changed to num. But still, I am getting different results at each call, is the problem about my shm pointers?